# How to automatically generate names of sections in head part of fancyhdr?

Tags: fancyhdr

I need to ask you a question, I want to make my fancyhdr to automaticly put the name of the section in the left corner, and the name of subsection of the same page on the right side of the head part of fancyhdr on that page, if there are more than 1 subsection, to just write the name of the first subsection. Can it be done automatically, or I need to make a lot of different fancyhdrs? Thank you all in advance.

```
  \documentclass[10pt,hidelinks]{article}
                       \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
                       \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
                       \usepackage[croatian]{babel}
                       \usepackage[left=30mm,top=25mm,right=25mm,bottom=30mm]{geometry}
                       \usepackage{fancyhdr}


                   \fancypagestyle{dokument}
                   {\lhead{} \chead{} \rhead{}
                   \lfoot{} \cfoot{\thepage{}} \rfoot{}
                   \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
                   }
           \begin{document}
\thispagestyle{dokument}
     \section{leftside}
    \subsection{rightside}
    \newpage
    \section{leftside2}
    \subsection{rightside2}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is your document two-sided or one-sided?

Comment: It's one-sided.

Comment: I don't think this is possible with `fancyhdr`, if I've understood correctly (well, it's possible, but far from easy). `titleps` makes things easier, but note I'm its author, so I'm biased :-). See the manual, p. 9. The problem is you need to use several mark registers, which must be properly synchronized, but `fancyhdr` only provides one.